# jQuery - slideToggle starting from middle and going out to the left and right

Tags: javascript, jquery

When I press my hamburger icon, I want my navigation menu to show and go from the middle to the left and right so it will fill the whole page.

I've created a codepen showing when it is dropping from the top to the bottom. But what I want it to do is going from the middle to the left and right.

I have been trying to search for an answer but without any luck.

**Link:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/dXvzRJ

```
<div class="button"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

.button{

 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background: #333;
}

.box{

 height: 400px;
 background: #000;
 display: none;
}

 $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.box').slideToggle('slow');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have this options:

**With CSS**

On css you can use `transition` to animate the `width` of the element:

```
.box{
  height: 400px;
  width:0;
  margin:0 auto;
  background: #000;
  transition:all .6s linear;
}
.box.open {
  width:100%;
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.box').toggleClass('open');
    });
});
```

[**Updated Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KMWvbV)

---

**With JqueryUI**

If you can include JqueryUI just use the `clip` effect :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.button').click(function(){
        $('.box').toggle( "clip", { direction: "horizontal" }, 1000 );
    });
 });
```

[**Codepen Demo**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/wWJqOw)

Comment: glad to help U @Fredrik